# Does activity requires Handler in android?

Tags: java, android

In an Android module, does an activity requires Handler to be defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a handler is a separate object class and so one would not need to be defined if you were making an Activity.

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

A handler would be used if you wanted to go do something in another thread/class and call back to the activity/ui.

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)